# ¿Cómo retornar la respuesta de un PHPMailer en la página del formulario de envío?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una página `.html` donde dentro contiene un `form action="fichero.php"` como sería lo normal. Me funciona, y me envía el correo.

Ahora bien, necesito que dependiendo de si el retorno del `php` es `true`o `false` salga en la misma página del `form` un pop-up que informe si el correo se ha enviado correctamente o no.

Actualmente me sale el log del cliente y un `echo` que le he configurado.

¿Cómo lo hago?
(Me sirve un ejemplo simple para saber qué estructura debo implementar para hacer esto)

Gracias de antemano y un saludo.

Comment: Ya tienes un tiempo considerable en el sitio, creo que no sería mal que pases a leer [ask] y [mcve], para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad y se te pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: No encuentro otra manera de hacer esta pregunta

Comment: Deberías poner tu HTM y tu PHP, eso es un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor forma seria hacerlo con AJAX, en lugar de enviar la petición a través del form, enviarla con Javascript.
Algo asi:

```js
function enviarPeticion() {
  var data = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
  var url = '/peticion.php';
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    var res = this.responseText;
    if(res === 'true'){
      alert('Enviado');
    }else{
      alert('Error');
    }
  };
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

Comment: Buenas Fernando, gracias por tu respuesta. La cosa es, el php debería seguir siendo igual? O tengo que cambiar todo el php para que predomine AJAX?

Comment: No, el php seguiria igual, si acaso lo que cambiaria seria que al final muestre un `echo 'true'` o `echo 'false'`, segun el resultado de la operacion, eso ya lo definirias tu, o hacer un echo con un json etc.